# Software to create transparent GIFs?

Tags: images, file-format, image-conversion, gif

I have to create GIFs with transparent backgrounds for a gig, I know Blender can render transparent videos with the quicktime codec, but do you know a tool to convert them to transparent GIFs? The only one I heard about is Photoshop, all online tools lower the resolution, and Virtualdub reduces the colors and doesn't convert to transparent GIF.

Comment: Hey @brockmann :). That means the edges of the transparent parts will be jagged (no anti-aliasing). But transparency itself should work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Blender cannot export/convert to GIF. Try folks at [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Jachym I use [Bligify](https://github.com/doakey3/Bligify) not perfect, I seem to remember i had to dip into the code to fix some old syntax? And, on Linux, kick it into persisting the paths to Gifsicle and ImageMagick, but it works..

Comment: Correct @JachymMichal, removed my comment.